# Refresh a LWC after record data is edited

Tags: lightning-web-components, refresh

I have a LWC that should be dynamic based on the data of the record
if a certain field is notNull then it will display a button and if is null, then it will not

the thing is that when I update my data, my LWC do not get updated .. I need to reload the page to see it ...

All the post I saw where to refresh a lwc after an action from the LWC such as save

Could someone give me a direction ?
thx you

[image]

This is the JS:

```js
    import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
    import CurrentOppData from '@salesforce/apex/CurrentOppPackageInfo.CurrentOppData';
    import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";
    import {updateRecord, getRecordNotifyChange} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
    import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
    import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
    
    export default class OpenCreatePackagesOnBackOffice extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
        OppData;
        @api recordId;
        isBoth = false;
        isPackageOnly = false;
        isToCreate = false;
        isWeired = false;
    
        @wire(CurrentOppData, { recordId: '$recordId' })
        OppInfo(wireResult) {
            const { error, data } = wireResult;
            this._wiredData = wireResult;
            if (data) {
                this.OppData = data;
                console.log('this is working')
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data[0]['Related_package_id__c'])
    
                if(data[0]['Related_package_id__c'] && data[0]['Related_Period_Id__c'] ){
                    this.isBoth = true
                } else if (data[0]['Related_package_id__c'] && !data[0]['Related_Period_Id__c']){
                    this.isPackageOnly = true;
                } else if ( !data[0]['Related_package_id__c'] && !data[0]['Related_Period_Id__c']) {
                    this.isToCreate = true;
                } else{
                    this.isWeired = true;
                }
            
            console.log('isBoth ' + this.isBoth);
            console.log('isPackageOnly ' + this.isPackageOnly);
            console.log('isPackageOnly ' + this.isToCreate);
            console.log('isWeired ' + this.isWeired);
            
            }
                
            else if (error) {
                this.error = error;
            }
        }
    
        handleClickOpenPackage() {
            
            const config = {
                type: 'standard__webPage',
                attributes: {
                    url: this.OppData[0]['OpenPackageOnBo__c']
                }
            };
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](config);
            console.log(this.OppData[0]['OpenPackageOnBo__c'])
          }
    
    }
```

My Apex:

```java
    public class CurrentOppPackageInfo {
        public CurrentOppPackageInfo(){
            
        }
        
        
        @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
        public static List <Opportunity> CurrentOppData (Id recordId){
            return[Select id, Related_package_id__c, Related_Period_Id__c, OpenPackageOnBo__c, createPackageOnBO__c, OpenPeriodOnBO__c
                   from Opportunity 
                   WHERE id = :recordId];
        }
    
    }
```

my HTML:

```html
    <template>
        <div class="slds-card slds-align_absolute-center slds-p-around_large">
            <template if:true={isBoth}>
                <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Open Package on Back Office" title="Primary action" onclick={handleClickOpenPackage} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button><br>
                <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Open Period on Back Office" title="Primary action" onclick={handleClickOpenPeriod} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
            </template>
            <template if:true={isPackageOnly}>
                <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Open Package on Back Office" title="Primary action" onclick={handleClickOpenPackage} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
            </template>
            <template if:true={isToCreate}>
                <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Create Package on Back Office" title="Primary action" onclick={handleClickCreate} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
            </template>
    
        </div>
        
    </template>
```

Comment: P.S. This is one of those times when you should have included your code. As it is, we have to guess why your data may not be refreshing.

Comment: Hi, 
sorry for that, I added everything

Comment: You have now a very comprehensive answer where before you would have only gotten a guess. Try to remember to include any relevant code when you have it, it makes a world of difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using Apex, use Lightning Data Service to get the data. This also demonstrates the use of importing field tokens, which are used for getRecord and getFieldValue. The magic of this code is that whenever the record is updated from the cache, your handleOpportunityData method will be called automatically.

```js
    import { LightningElement, wire, api } from "lwc";
    import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
    import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";
    import Related_Period_Id__c from "@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Related_Period_Id__c";
    import Related_package_id__c from "@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Related_package_id__c";
    import OpenPackageOnBo__c from "@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.OpenPackageOnBo__c";
    
    export default class OpenCreatePackagesOnBackOffice extends NavigationMixin(
      LightningElement
    ) {
      @api recordId;
      isBoth;
      isPackageOnly;
      isToCreate;
      isWeired;
      error;
      openPackageOnBo;
    
      @wire(getRecord, {
        recordId: "$recordId",
        fields: [Related_Period_Id__c, Related_package_id__c, OpenPackageOnBo__c],
      })
      handleOpportunityData(wireResult) {
        const { error, data } = wireResult;
        this.isBoth = false;
        this.isPackageOnly = false;
        this.isToCreate = false;
        this.isWeired = false;
        if (data) {
          const hasPackage = !!getFieldValue(data, Related_package_id__c);
          const hasPeriod = !!getFieldValue(data, Related_Period_Id__c);
          this.isBoth = hasPackage && hasPeriod;
          this.isisPackage = hasPackage && !hasPeriod;
          this.isToCreate = !hasPackage && !hasPeriod;
          this.isWeired = !hasPackage && hasPeriod;
          this.openPackageOnBo = getFieldValue(data, OpenPackageOnBo__c);
        }
        // If you need this, you should also show it somewhere.
        this.error = error;
      }
    
      handleClickOpenPackage() {
        const config = {
          type: "standard__webPage",
          attributes: {
            url: this.openPackageOnBo,
          },
        };
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](config);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Amazing I learnt something today ! Thx you very much ;)